# Is PHP universal in all browsers?

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP for an email-based order form using `mail()`. Because PHP is server-side, does this mean that there are no circumstances that PHP wouldn't be able to communicate with the computer?

Is there a "disable PHP" option in any browsers like there is with JavaScript? Can I count on every browser with internet access being able to (or at least "doing it's best to") communicate with the PHP server?

Comment: Your PHP server merely squirts HTML to the client. To all intents and purposes the client will behave no differently than if it had been a static HTML file sent.

Comment: Webbrowsers only understands HTML. PHP runs on webserver and produces HTML. Communication takes place by HTTP.

Comment: Why do people downvote this ? It is a legitimate question, even though it's entry-level.

Comment: @driis because it's google-level -> not valid on SO. See, a moderator closed it. Mods know what they are doing and why...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, PHP will work in all browsers.

PHP has nothing to do with browsers, its a server side language.  PHP code is executed on the server, generating HTML which is then sent to the client. The client would receive the results of running that script.

check this link [What is PHP?](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php)

[image]

Comment: had to vote for 2 reasons. 1st Good answer, 2nd cool graphics!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much yes, browsers just render html/css and javascript. What you use to generate it doesn't matter for the most part

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that PHP is compatible with all browsers. The browser doesn't know about the architecture that's serving pages and therefore, can't disable it.

The difference between PHP and JavaScript is that JavaScript runs in the browser and can therefore be disabled by the user.

That said, it is entirely possible to generate pages from PHP that a particular browser might have problems with, but that's not an issue specific to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, php will "work" on all browsers.

The client doesn't "communicate" with a php server, it communicates with a web server. Your client requests a page, and the web server returns one. How the page is generated (either a static html file or using some kind of server side scripting language like php) generally makes no difference to the browser.

Php does not "execute php code" on the client machine, it simply returns html/css, and sometimes javascript that instructs the browser what to display.

Answer (score 1):

PHP, as you point out, is a server-side language. The visitor's web browser never sees the PHP code, only the HTML or XHTML or XML generated by the PHP script that is run by the server. So using PHP will not rule out the use of any browser, but the product generated by PHP may be incompatible. For instance, if you generate HTML5 with your PHP script then there is a good chance that older browsers won't be able to render the pages well. But the same would be true if you simply used static HTML5 pages without generating them with PHP.

In short, you are safe to use PHP without worrying about it causing browser compatibility issues. But you do need to think about the product generated by your PHP which gets sent to the visitor's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Php is a server side programming language, that is interpreted before it reaches the front end user.

That means that the user have no idea that there has even been a php script running.

Javascript on the other hand is run on the client side, from the web browser, and that's why the user can decide to turn it off.