# how to hide the mysql database name in php file

Tags: php, mysql

I include the PHP file database connectivity using:

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','tam');
mysql_selectdb("student",$con);
```

or

```
include('dbconn.php')
```

with this type of conncectivity.

Here, `student` is the database name. One problem has occurred, I developed my page in this type of coding but a third person or other viewers can view the database name show in the PHP file. I don't have to show the database name in the PHP file,so how can I solve this type of problem or how can I hide the database name in my MySQL settings?

Comment: Please format your post well...

Comment: Q: You're aware that code in your .php source file doesn't get transmitted over to the client browser, correct?  The code is only visible to those with file access on the server.

Comment: check the image in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438911/is-php-universal-in-all-browsers/12438921#12438921

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code is not sent to the user (it's not like javascript), so the only people who could read your DB name and password are ones who already have access to all your files on the server. If they can do that, you're already massively compromised, and there's no point in worrying about hiding the name.

However, what you can do is declare your DB name and password as constants in a separate PHP file, and include that one file in all the pages where you use the DB. That makes it easier to distribute your code to others without worrying about taking out the DB connection information everywhere you might have used it. It also makes things easier if you ever change your password or DB name.

Comment: You need to do is write a file with lines like `define("DBNAME", "your real database name")` and `define("DBPASS", "your real password")` and then include that file using `require()` when you want to access your database. Then you can establish the connection using DBNAME and DBPASS rather than putting in your actual info.